# Does Firestore retries when write failed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a case where my web app has to update two collections. I wonder if write to one collection is successful while the other is failed due to connection lost, will firestore retries once the connection is up again?

if no, is that means i have to undo the sucessful write ( is it the best practice?)? Otherwise the data will be inconsistent and break the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a write operation can't be completed due to a loss of network connection it will be retried once the connection is restored.

It's best to think of Firestore as a synchronized document storage. It automatically synchronizes local changes to the server, and changes from the server to the client (when there is an active observer).